# Array to lista con sublistas

Tags: python, array, python-3.x, lista

estoy intentando convertir un Array a una lista de sublistas, de tal manera que:

```
input: '004013087631908524907452613506180379198735046740200801375849102802367495060021030'

output: [[0,0,4,0,1,3,0,8,7],[6,3,1,9,0,8,5,2,4],[9,0,7,4,5,2,6,1,3],[0,6,1,8,0,3,7,9,1],[9,8,7,3,5,0,4,6,7],[4,0,2,0,0,8,0,1,3],[7,5,8,4,9,1,0,2,8],[0,2,3,6,7,4,9,5,0],[6,0,0,2,1,0,3,0]]
```

esto es lo que he conseguido hacer

```
def arr2sud(l):
   y = [l[i:i+9] for i in range(0, len(l), 9)]
   f = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
   for i in range(len(y)):
      d = ",".join(y[i])
      f[i]=d
   return f
```

pero el **output** es: `['0,0,4,0,1,3,0,8,7', '6,3,1,9,0,8,5,2,4', '9,0,7,4,5,2,6,1,3', '5,0,6,1,8,0,3,7,9', '1,9,8,7,3,5,0,4,6', '7,4,0,2,0,0,8,0,1', '3,7,5,8,4,9,1,0,2', '8,0,2,3,6,7,4,9,5', '0,6,0,0,2,1,0,3,0']`

Es decir, devuelve una lista de arrays.
Sé que se puede hacer con numpy, pero no quiero utilizarlo.
Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Algo un poco enrevesado en una línea:

```
x = '004013087631908524907452613506180379198735046740200801375849102802367495060021030'
result = [list(map(int, list(x[i:i+9]))) for i in range(0, len(x), 9)]
```

Comment: Funciona, pero la respuesta sería mas completa si explicaras esa línea, o si dieras su equivalente "desenrollado" sin comprensiones de listas y sin `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un bucle mas, el cual que itere sobre `f`, ejemplo:

```
def arr2sud(l):
   y = [l[i:i+9] for i in range(0, len(l), 9)]
   f = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

   for q in range(len(f)):
    for i in range(len(y)):
      d = ",".join(y[i])
   f[q]=d
return f
```